# How to obtain the best fit?

Tags: optimization, curves, data-analysis, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization

I have a complex function say $f(x,a,b,c)$ where $x$ is variable and $a,b,c$ are the parameters. Parameters $a,b$ are linked as $d = (1/a^2) - (i*pi/b)$. The limits of x is very small say -0.02 to 0.02

```
f(x,d,c) = (Abs[0.5*Sqrt[Pi/d]*Exp[-(((Pi*x)^2)/d]*(1 - Erf[c*Sqrt[d] + I*Pi*x/Sqrt[d]])])^2
```

Now when I numerically integrate this function w.r.t $x$ for a particular value of $c$, I get a point and a list of values of $c$ gives me list of points (keeping $a,b$ constant at some value). Joining these points resembles a curve similar to Error function.

Now I have a data set of points and points from $f(x)$, using these two I have to optimize values of $a,b$ to obtain the best fit.

How can I do this? I just know the least squares method of regression and have no knowledge of curve fittings.

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Assuming you're not going to hardcode everything by yourself, MATLAB's fminsearch and it's counterparts may help. Related tools in other computer algebra software are easily findable in Internet.

Comment: @ValerySaharov Yeah I tried Mathematica and Matlab both, the problem with Matlab is a complex error function is not defined and am currently stuck in Mathematica.
Apart from that these software functions require an expression to be defined whereas my expression is the numerical integration of the above mentioned function so I am confused whether I can use numerical integration as an expression. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

If we have both correctly transcribed the problem, it is ill-posed.

The Mathematica definition and a sample result for $x=0$ are shown below:

[image: Mathematica]

The function has a Gaussian appearance. The plot shows $f(x,1,1)$.

[image: function]

The total error is plotted for $x=0$ as a function of $c$ (horizontal) and $d$ (vertical). The extremum is a rough point on the boundary edge.

[image: contour plot]

To visualize the problem, create a mesh. For example
$$
 x = \left\{-0.2, -0.195, -0.19, \cdots, 0.195, 0.2 \right\}.
$$

At each point on the mesh, solve for the values of $(c,d)$ which minimizes $f$. The results show numerical oscillations. For $c$:

[image: c]

For $d$

[image: d]

In this state, the problem is not ready for least squares.